# What type of ANN architecture to choose?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I have N number of teachers each of which has an input feature vector (25 dimensional) consisting of positive numerical values for different quality of aspects (for example, lecturing ability, knowledge capacity, communication skills, etc). I want to design a ANN to output a single quality index based on these quality features. What type of ANN architecture is appropriate for this problem?

Comment: As per the given features, we don't have any temporal or spatial relationships among the features, so we can use a simple full-connected NN.

Comment: is your comment still valid when features are correlated?

Comment: No. Suppose the features are temporally related to each other, then we can't treat them as individual features. For instance, the sales of a company in a year, form a time series. We can't treat each month's sales as an individual feature, as each month's sales depend on the previous months' sales.

Comment: If you're working on an image classification problem, you're trying to implement a model which can learn the patterns in spatial features among the given images.

Comment: The problem  I want to solve is as above (please see the question). For this problem, lecturing ability and  communication skills are two different  features but still there is some correlation between lecturing ability  and communication skills.